# Error 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte cuando el origen de los ficheros es la carperta Descargas

Tags: python, pandas, archivo, utf-8, os

Estoy escribiendo un programa que enlista todos los archivos con extensión .csv de una carpeta específica, utilizando la función listdir del módulo os. Luego, los lee con pandas y los agrupa en un DataFrame para finalmente enviarlos a sql server. El error ocurre cuando los archivos se encuentran en la carpeta que existe por defecto para **'Descargas'**; mientras que si los archivos se encuentran en cualquier otra carpeta creada por mí, el programa funciona correctamente. Mi inconveniente es que necesito que lea los archivos desde la carpeta Descargas porque tengo otro script que previamente los ha descargado allí.

Dejo la parte problemática del código:

```
#Importamos la librería de Pandas
import pandas as pd

#Importamos los métodos para ubicar los archivos
import os
from os.path import join

ruta = r'C:\Users\miUsuario\Downloads' 
archivos = os.listdir(rutaGGPS) #Lista con los nombres de los archivos csv
datosTotales = pd.DataFrame() #Df vacío para guardar todos los df

for archivo in archivos: #Bucle para recorrer cada archivo csv
    rutaArchivo = join(ruta, archivo) #extraer la ruta de cada archivo

    # Extraemos el dato placa como una variable string
    def filas(row):
        if row==1:
            return False
        else:
            return row
    #Leer archivo omitiendo las filas FALSE
    tablaPlaca=pd.read_csv(rutaArchivo, sep=";", skiprows=filas)
    placa=tablaPlaca.loc[0, 'Movimientos y detenciones'] #Variable placa

    # Creamos un dataframe a partir de cada archivo excluyendo las 3 líneas del encabezado innecesarias
    datosIniciales=pd.read_csv(rutaArchivo, sep=";", skiprows=3)

    #Creamos un DataFrame con las columnas que nos interesan
    datosLimpios = pd.DataFrame(datosIniciales, columns = ['Estado', 'Evento', 'Fecha', 'Velocidad GPS (Km/h)','Ubicación', 'T. Entrada Difusor', 'Latitud', 'Longitud'])
    
    # Agregamos una columna que nos guarde la placa
    datosFinales=datosLimpios.assign(Placa=placa)
    
    #Concatenamos todos los df para crear un único df final 
    datosTotales = pd.concat([datosTotales, datosFinales])
    datosTotales.index = range(datosTotales.shape[0]) #Reiniciamos los índices del df
```

Posdata: Ya intenté mover los archivos de la carpeta 'Descargas' a cualquier otra carpeta utilizando Shutil, pero lo que sucede entonces es que mueve los archivos, sale el mismo error y el programa se detiene sin ejecutar las demás instrucciones.

Comment: ¿Funciona si pones a los pd.read_csv(), `encoding='unicode_escape'` ? Ver [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50538501/1545868) (en inglés)

Comment: Muchas gracias, parece que funcionó. Pues en realidad pasó algo muy extraño; puse los encoding y empezó a correr bien esa parte, pero me salió un nuevo error de sql que me decía que algunos datos tenían un tipo inconsistente con el asignado a la columna (creo que la columna era FLOAT y algunos datos no lo eran o algo así). Entonces volví a quitar los encoding y ya siguió corriendo correctamente. Ojalá no vuelva a fallar más adelante.